# Same query works different on two different machines

Tags: mysql

This MySQL query

```
SELECT id FROM product WHERE title LIKE '%spoon%'
```

works fine on in MySQL on machine #1 and returns all products with `spoon` anywhere in the title string

```
('black spoon', 'teaspoon', 'red spoons')
```

Some time ago I migrated the whole thing to a machine #2 but the exact same query returns different number of results and from some reason it only returns products with word `teaspoons` in the title (no eg. `black spoon` among the results)

Both MySql servers are version 5.0.51a. That particular product table is exactly the same on both machines with all fields the exact same type, length etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds odd. Is your data definitely exactly as per the question (no differences in case for example)?

Comment: It's the same - structure and data. It was exported from one database and imported to a new one with phpmyadmin. All other aspects and queries of the whole web site are ok. Just this LIKE one works oddly

Comment: Both tables have the same db-engine (Innodb, MyIsam,...)? What's the output of `show variables like "%character%";`?

Comment: Thanks Ocaso. The collation on the table was actually different (utf8 where the old one had latin1). I wonder though. How this works on mysql level that utf8 don't recognize like %spoon% search correctly?

Answer (score 1):

do you check if your encoding charset are the same in both databases?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure the problem is not in the database engine(you might want to check that (Inno,etc)) or anything like that. Check your connection config files. You might be connecting to a different database.